# how to speed up the process using canvas tag to display decoded h.264 packet inside browser plugin?

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, browser, h.264, firebreath

I am new to browser plugin and firebreath. I tried to build a plugin which decode h264 packet and then display the video frame into canvas tag on browser html5. But I tested to modify 100x100 canvas pixels through my plugin, it took 3-4 seconds to just change a rect color.

here are part of my html code

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

here are part of my javascript inside body tag

```
<script>
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
var imgData=ctx.createImageData(100,100);
for (var i=0;i<imgData.data.length;i+=4) {
    imgData.data[i+0]=255;
    imgData.data[i+1]=0;
    imgData.data[i+2]=0;
    imgData.data[i+3]=255;
}
ctx.putImageData(imgData,0,0);

function delayFunctionTest() {
    console.log('test\n');
    plugin().changeImagePixel(imgData.data);
    ctx.putImageData(imgData,0,0);
}
setTimeout(function(){delayFunctionTest()}, 2000);
</script>
```

here my pluginapi.cpp

```
void sanypluginAPI::changeImagePixel(FB::JSObjectPtr& imageData)
{
    unsigned long i;

    for(i=0;i<imageData->GetProperty("length").convert_cast<unsigned long>();i+=4){
        imageData->SetProperty(i, 0);
        imageData->SetProperty(i+1, 100);
        imageData->SetProperty(i+2, 155);
        imageData->SetProperty(i+3, 255);
    }
}
```

The code above took 3-4 seconds to change the rect color after the word 'test' shown up on console. Is there anyway to speed up the process of changing canvas pixel data inside browser plugin? Or anything wrong with my naive coding? Or my plugin is just not possible to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to directly access the canvas pixel data; your best bet is (now don't hit me) to base64 encode it and pass it to javascript as a string, then decode it.

Yes, I know.  I know.

Comment: Thank you for your replay and your awesome firebreath. Actually I not so sure how the memory management on JSObjectPtr, I thought my pluginAPI changeImagePixel was directly changing the canvas pixel data? Or does you mean that the speed bottleneck is because of the type conversion?

Comment: the speed bottleneck is actually that every time you make a call into Javascript it has to make a call across the process boundary. This means that you're much better off passing a lot of data in a single call than passing a little data in a lot of calls.  That's why base64 is faster

Comment: I tried your method. Pass only the string to my plugin function. Then my plugin function return back a string which contain modified image data in string. This indeed speed up the overall process. Thank you for your enlightenment. but I noticed that the speed isn't really realistic if I want to display a video with 30 fps. before I mark answered, just wanna get your advice, is my approach right? Look like I better decode and display the video on windowed plugin instead of windowless plugin with html5 display.

Comment: I think it is safe to say that if you have video that is being driven by a plugin, the only performant way to display it is with the plugin. There simply isn't a good enough way to pass large chunks of data to and from javascript.